# Regex add space between all punctuation

Tags: java, regex

I need to add spaces between all punctuation in a string.

```
\\ "Hello: World." -> "Hello : World ."
\\ "It's 9:00?"    -> "It ' s 9 : 00 ?"
\\ "1.B,3.D!"      -> "1 . B , 3 . D !"
```

I think a regex is the way to go, matching all non-punctuation `[a-ZA-Z\\d]+`, adding a space before and/or after, then extracting the remainder matching all punctuation `[^a-ZA-Z\\d]+`.

But I don't know how to (recursively?) call this regex. Looking at the first example, the regex will only match the `"Hello"`. I was thinking of just building a new string by continuously removing and appending the first instance of the matched regex, while the original string is not empty.

```java
private String addSpacesBeforePunctuation(String s) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final String nonpunctuation = "[a-zA-Z\\d]+";
    final String punctuation = "[^a-zA-Z\\d]+";

    String found;
    while (!s.isEmpty()) {

        // regex stuff goes here

        found = ???; // found group from respective regex goes here
        builder.append(found);
        builder.append(" ");
        s = s.replaceFirst(found, "");
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();
}
```

However this doesn't feel like the right way to go... I think I'm over complicating things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lookarounds based regex using punctuation property `\p{Punct}` in Java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)(?:(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct}))(?=\\S)", " ");
```

- `(?<=\\S)` Asserts if prev char is not a white-space
- `(?<=\\p{Punct})` asserts a position if previous char is a punctuation char
- `(?=\\p{Punct})` asserts a position if next char is a punctuation char
- `(?=\\S)` Asserts if next char is not a white-space

[IdeOne Demo](http://ideone.com/WMtYR1)

Comment: Now it adds a space at the end of the string if there is a punctuation there.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Very good catch. I have fixed it, check my updated regex and demo now.

Comment: @anubhava Lousy connection. Have to quit. See RealSkeptic's comment!

Comment: @laune: Yes I've updated regex based on that comment, please check it now.

Comment: @anubhava  Now... if you adopt the negation used in dasblinkelight's regex you simplify it a little, and do it in a single regex pass, which is better than that solution. `"(?<=\\S)(?:(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct}))(?=\\S)"`

Comment: @anubhava And I think a little less headache-causing when trying to understand it is this: `"(?<=\\S)(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})(?=\\S)"`

Comment: @laune: Yes that's right `(?<=\\S)(?:(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct}))(?=\\S)` will work fine (edited).

Answer (score 2):

When you see a punctuation mark, you have four possibilities:

1. Punctuation is surrounded by spaces
2. Punctuation is preceded by a space
3. Punctuation is followed by a space
4. Punctuation is neither preceded nor followed by a space.

Here is code that does the replacement properly:

```
String ss = s
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\S)\\p{Punct}", " $0")
    .replaceAll("\\p{Punct}(?=\\S)", "$0 ");
```

It uses two expressions - one matching the number 2, and one matching the number 3. Since the expressions are applied on top of each other, they take care of the number 4 as well. The number 1 requires no change.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/6d7S54)